# Card Text alignment in react Card Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, card

I have following code for creating a grid of cards , but the LINK button at the bottom is not aligned in all the cards. What do I need to change to get all the link buttons aligned in all the card at the bottom right. Please see the image at the bottom, I would like all the select button to be horizontally aligned with other cards in the row.

```js
  
 <Row xs={1} md={4} className="g-4">
   {MilitaryFormsType.map((e, idx) => (
     <Col>
       <Card border="#f7f7f7" style={{ width: '18rem', height: '18rem', whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap' }}>
            <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title>{e.name}</Card.Title>
            <Card.Text >{e.Description}</Card.Text>
             <Link to={e.link} >
             <Button variant="primary" style={{ backgroundColor: "#aa92df", borderStyle: "none", float: "right" }}>Select</Button>
              </Link>
              </Card.Body>
   </Card>
  </Col>
  ))}
</Row>
```

[image]

Comment: They are already horizontally aligned (they are on the right hand side of the card). So I guess you want them to be vertically aligned, so they are all at the bottom of the card ?

Comment: The reason your buttons are all up and down the way they're is because of the length of your description so either you have a defined size for your description or you truncate the descriptions that are too long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand from a problem is you want to move the button on the right bottom of all cards.
You can use position "relative" on the body and for link position "absolute".

```
<Card.Body style={{ position: "relative" }}>
  <Card.Title>{e.name}</Card.Title>
  <Card.Text>{e.Description}</Card.Text>
  <Link to={e.link} style={{ position: "absolute", bottom: 0, right: 0 }}>
    <Button
      variant="primary"
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "#aa92df",
        borderStyle: "none",
        float: "right",
      }}
    >
      Select
    </Button>
  </Link>
</Card.Body>
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Try this one if using wrap it's possible **

```html
<Card.Body>
            <Card.Title>{e.name}</Card.Title>
            <Card.Text >{e.Description}</Card.Text>
             <Link to={e.link} >
             <div style={{ text-align:center }}>
             <Button variant="primary" style={{ backgroundColor: "#aa92df", borderStyle: "none"}}>Select</Button>
             </div>
              </Link>
</Card.Body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can dynamically control the height of `Card.Title`, `Card.Text` and others using javascript. Below is the code of how you can make all the heights the same so the cards are aligned while containing all the data without overflowing. The principle is basically to set all the cards' heights equal to the height of the longest card. Below is the code:

```
const [cardHeight, setCardHeight] = useState(null);

const getMaxHeightTitle = (elements) => {
let titleHeights = Array.prototype.map.call(elements, (element, i) => {
  return element.offsetHeight;
 });
 return Math.max(...titleHeights);
}

const setMaxContent = (elements) => {
 Array.prototype.map.call(elements, (element, i) => {
   element.style.height = 'max-content';
 });
}

const setMaxHeightTitle = useCallback((elements, h) => {
 Array.prototype.map.call(elements, (element, i) => {
   if (element.offsetHeight !== cardHeight) {
    element.style.height = cardHeight + 'px'
   }
  });
 }, [cardHeight]);

const resizeCardTitle = useCallback(() => {
 setMaxContent(document.getElementsByClassName('card-title h5'));
 titleHeight = getMaxHeightTitle(document.getElementsByClassName('card-title h5'));
 setCardHeight(titleHeight)
 setMaxHeightTitle(document.getElementsByClassName('card-title h5'), titleHeight);
}, [setMaxHeightTitle]);

useEffect(() => {
 window.addEventListener('load', resizeCardTitle);
 window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCardTitle);
 return () => {
  window.removeEventListener('load', resizeCardTitle);
  window.removeEventListener('resize', resizeCardTitle);
}

}, [cardHeight, resizeCardTitle]);
useEffect(() => {
 resizeCardTitle();
}, [resizeCardTitle])
```